# Rails 5 - Many to Many checkboxes or radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Ok so I have Option's which are grouped into OptionGroup's. OptionGroup has a boolean attribute called :multiple which determines if multiple options from the group can be selected, or only a single option from the group.  I also have a LineItem model which has a many to many relationship with the Option model.

Here are my models

```
class OptionGroup < ApplicationRecord
  # Uses :multiple, a boolean attribute to determine if multiple can be selected
  has_many :options
end

class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :option_group
end

class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_item_options
  has_many :options, through: line_item_options
end

class LineItemOption < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :option
  belongs_to :line_item
end
```

The issue I'm up against here, is that some option groups will only allow a single option from the group to be selected(radio buttons), and some option_groups will allow any combinations of options to be selected.

In LineItemsController I have:

```
private
  def line_item_params
    params.require(:line_item).permit(:some, :list, :of, :params, options_ids: [])
```

In my line_item form, how would I alternate between radio buttons, and check boxes, based on the option's option_group.multiple attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This called [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association, update the `Option` class like below

```
class Option < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :option_group

    has_many :line_item_options
    has_many :line_items, through: line_item_options
end
```